# Python - How to add primitives to the selection?

Tags: python

How to add primitives like `box`, `cylinder`, `sphere`, and `capsule` objects based on the bounding box or selected verts in edit mode of any object?

Example -

`Object Mode`

[image]

`Edit Mode`

[image]

Comment: Do you want to control the sphere size base on the cube?

Comment: yes, sphere size is based on the cube, any object or selected verts

Comment: Not all objects have a [circumsphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_sphere), and 3 points have an infinite number

Comment: I want to cover object bound box or mesh bound box with the sphere

Comment: Do you have the coordinates of the bbox?

Comment: I don't know how to do

Answer (score 1):

Since the bounding box is a tetrahedron you can use Wolfram's [Circumsphere](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumsphere.html) entry for your calculations.  Assuming an object at the origin, the following code will give you the sphere for that object's bounding box. `v[0]` is the lower left front corner as seen from front view.  The other coordinates are the left top front, left bottom rear, and right bottom front, giving the relationship $(l_1, l_2, l_3)$ are the corresponding $(z, y, x)$ lengths.

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

def vsub(a, b):
    return (a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1], a[2] - b[2])

def vlen(v):
    return sqrt(v[0]*v[0] + v[1]*v[1] + v[2]*v[2])

cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
    
v = cube.bound_box

l1 = vlen(vsub(v[0], v[1]))
l2 = vlen(vsub(v[0], v[3]))
l3 = vlen(vsub(v[0], v[4]))

d = sqrt(l1*l1 + l2*l2 + l3*l3) / 2


mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Sphere')
sphere = bpy.data.objects.new("Sphere", mesh)

bpy.context.collection.objects.link(sphere)

# Construct the bmesh sphere and assign it to the blender mesh.
bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bm, u_segments=32, v_segments=16, diameter=d)
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()
```

The vector math routines are because the bounding box is returned as an 8 x 3 matrix and it's easier to use the two subroutines than to convert the matrix into vectors.

Comment: How to add a sphere to the selected verts' bound box?

Comment: figure out what the bounding box is and use the above algorithm with the bounding box you generated rather than the object bounding box.